# Magento 1.9 - Free shipping not working with cart price rule

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

I have set up a cart price rule which provides free shipping if a product is found from the mentioned category but it is not working properly, coupon code is getting applied on the front-end but it is not reflecting shipping price on checkout.

What I am doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287157/magento-1-9-shopping-cart-rule-for-free-shipping-not-working/287160#287160

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the affected categories in the Conditions:

[image]

Comment: Not working, I have tried this way also